# Unity builds: lag spikes in playmode and builds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, urp

All game builds have 3 sec freezes or lags every 1-2 minutes despite 60-90FPS.

Got a scene with RigidBody based Character followed by 2 NPC. URP 2021 LTS.

things tried so far:
Downsized big textures; turned Shadows/Aliasing/HDR/ off; Camera clip plane to 500.

Post Processing off; Got rid of Idle anim (just run and attack left); Rigidbody Interpolate/Ex; Vsync on/off; GPU skinning on/off, Reduced number of colliders to minimum only for Rigidbodies.

target framerate 60. Any help?

GB allocations only happens when Cinemachines is used(Its GUI causes GB). Profiler shows render and cam loads in playerloop.

[image]

[image]

Anyone have a solution to get rid of these freezes?

Comment: 1.87ms is not the issue, it looks more to be the 13.17ms element.. whats that?

Comment: i'm not that deep into profile but i believe it's render pipelene itself.  i noticed pipeline context always pops up.  it's also camera stack that takes ms.  i'm running out of options waht to try here.  Freezes happen as if  scheduled 3 sec every 2 minute.

Comment: This question is fine, please don't close it. @Ocitan - are you able to test with different hardware?

Comment: unfortunetely not for now.  i'm suspecting some hardware issues too.  but i want to rule out all -things -unity first.  I know this engine has quite a history of spikes issues.  think main culprits might be camera and movement interpolation.  but switching between rigidbds and char controllers and cinemachine on/off didn't yield results yet.

Comment: what about culling?

Comment: yep, tried  cam culling on and off.  changing timestep didn't help either. same goes for doing animation scripting in fixed update.  same for movement in just update and camera scripts in late/fixed update just for the sake of it. nothing for now.

Comment: even 13ms are actually still within the range of normal ... 60FPS means ~17ms / frame .. is there any chance you can profile on the actual target device (e.g. via development build)? Depends a bit what exactly this runs on

Comment: it's pretty much the same. building for PC so testing it on the target. i suspected imported models.  my Playerloop with custom models may have around 22 ms sometimes. thought around 400k for a few models were too much. but simple meshes hooked up to char controller give around 10ms but the issue is still there.  Key thing it's hapenning when there's movement.   Changed fancy rotating cam to simple follow behind. same story. just like with RB to ChController.   i don't know what else to  try..  – 
derHugo